# How do I integrate a custom input argument into a Graphene DjangoFilterConnectionField queryset?

Tags: python-3.x, graphene-python, pgvector

I'm wondering what the cleanest way to integrate [a Graphene DjangoFilterConnectionField custom input argument](https://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/queries/#arguments) into the default queryset is?

I'm iterating on the following Graphene Query class whose custom input attribute attempts to integrate the [PgVector CosineDistance](https://github.com/pgvector/pgvector-python/blob/master/pgvector/django/__init__.py#L85-L87) function:

```
class Query(graphene.ObjectType):

    all_the_small_things = DjangoFilterConnectionField(
        VectorNode,
        embedding=graphene.List(graphene.Float),
    )

    def resolve_all_the_small_things(
        root,
        info,
        **kwargs,
    ):
        from pgvector.django import CosineDistance

        annotations = {}

        if kwargs.get("embedding"):
            annotations["embedding"] = CosineDistance(
                "embedding", kwargs.pop("embedding")
            )

        if annotations:
            # How best to integrate this into the existing behavior?
            # VectorNode.objects.annotate(**annotations)
            # now use filter functionality provided by
            # the default resolver.
```

I would like to augment the default query behavior (i.e. filtering) if the custom input is provided and use the default behavior as-is if it isn't. Do I need to implement my own queryset and/or filterset? Is there a way to reflect/modify the default behavior using the function arguments?

Note: I think the long term answer to this is to add support for PG Vector columns to Graphene and/or creating a django-filters filter subclass but I really need to understand how this all comes together before seriously thinking about how to approach any of that upstream.